# Where can I find the original text of Hungary's controversial new child protection bill?

Tags: law, reference-request, hungary

I have read that there has been a new bill proposed in Hungary which, according to the Hungarian Prime Minister, seeks to protect children, but which has also been criticised for being anti-LGBT.

Does anybody know where I can find the original wording or a full translation of the bill?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5855/should-the-controversy-of-a-bill-be-edited-into-a-question). Feel free to post your opinions on what this question should look like there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Hungarian text of the law, entitled "2021. évi LXXIX. törvény: a pedofil bűnelkövetőkkel szembeni szigorúbb fellépésről, valamint a gyermekek védelme érdekében egyes törvények módosításáról" (on stepping up action against pedophile offenders and amending certain laws to protect children) can be read as published by the Hungarian *Nemzeti Jogszabálytár* (National Legislation) service [here](http://archiv.njt.hu/cgi_bin/njt_doc.cgi?docid=249873.426375).

It includes the controversial sections restricting media which portrays divergence from self-identity corresponding to sex at birth, sex change, or homosexuality for people under the age of 18 (section 9), as well as that prohibiting the promotion of these topics in education (section 11).

These provisions, and others, have been roundly criticised by EU leaders, with Dutch PM Mark Rutte [commenting](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-57596263) that Hungary "has no business being in the European Union any more", and EU commissioners Thierry Breton and Didier Reynders [writing to Hungarian Justice Minister Judit Varga](https://twitter.com/EU_Commission/status/1407704051416973314) informing her that if the Bill enters into force, "the European Commission will not hesitate to take action in line with its powers under the [Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union]".

On the other hand, the Polish ambassador to Berlin defended the law, saying that "This has nothing to do with intolerance, let alone persecuting homosexuals."

Comment: The last two paragraphs don’t answer the question.

Comment: @EkadhSingh Yes, but they qualify why people might find this law a mess and they avoid just giving it free publicity.